# How to restrict the decimal places in awk without rounding off

Tags: awk

I want to print 0.74 for 0.748.

If I use

```
awk '{printf "%0.2f\n",$1}' filename
```

for 0.748 it prints 0.75. But I want 0.74 and remove remaining part.
For 77.348 it should be 77.34.

Any ideas?

There is no

```
gawk -M
```

option to use ROUNDMODE="Z" ??

Even I couldn't find ceiling and floor functions as well.

Comment: Have you considered printing it as a string e.g. `"%.4s\n"`?

Comment: @steeldriver Consider there are two values 4.567 and  77.657 for example. Now using %.1s in printf prints 4 and 7 respectively. But I need it as 4 and 77. It is not taking care of dot here

Comment: If you just want the integer part, you can use the `%d` conversion specifier. On 15.04 with GNU awk 4.1.1, it is possible to use MPFR to set the `ROUNDMODE` explicitly - see [Setting the Rounding Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Setting-Rounding-Mode.html#Setting-Rounding-Mode) but AFAIK that's not available in other versions/varieties

Comment: Use regular expressions to chop the part you need..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`

- with `print`

  ```
  awk -F. '{print $1"."substr($2,1,2)}' filename
  ```

or

- with `printf`

  ```
  awk -F. '{printf "%0.2f\n",$1"."substr($2,1,2)}' filename
  ```

---

Example

```
$ awk -F. '{print $1"."substr($2,1,2)}' foo
0.74
77.65

$ awk -F. '{printf "%0.2f\n",$1"."substr($2,1,2)}' foo
0.74
77.65

$ cat foo
0.748
77.657
```